# Export Data out of HDFS to remote server

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

I want to Copy files without touching encoding to a remote server. I found one solution using webHDFS but Its not working due to in sufficient permission. Any other ways I can achieve it.

```
pbrun -u username curl -i -L "http://j12343.intranet.com:50070/webhdfs/v1/bigdatahdfs/landing/brns/test1.txt?op=OPEN" -o /data_dev/project/test.txt
```

Comment: `hdfs dfs -get http://j12343.intranet.com:50070/bigdatahdfs/landing/brns/test1.txt`? What do you mean "touching encoding" though?

Comment: @cricket_007 this will get file from HDFS to edge node. Please understand my query, I just want to export file as it is to remote server from HDFS.

Comment: No, that downloads a file wherever you run the command at... Works the exact same as WebHDFS. There is no command to take a file from Hadoop to a remote server directly. You must download the file, then SCP or rsync to the remote destination. Otherwise, you can SSH to the remote server first, and then run either command

Comment: @cricket_007 I ran command on remote server. It say hdfs command not found.

Comment: Well, you would need to download and configure Hadoop commands there, but it should work once you do

Comment: Can you specify steps needed for that. And what configuration are required for same... Any other solutions are most welcome.

Comment: On the Apache Hadoop page, there are download links. Make sure you get the same version as the Hadoop cluster, and you don't want the `src` or `sources` downloads... Once you extract that, there is a `bin/` folder where the hdfs command exists, and there is a `conf/` folder that you generally would copy from your existing edge node config folder to there... At that point, you basically made a new edge node... The easier way here would just be to use/fix WebHDFS

Comment: Also note that you need to configure the DNS names of the master and slaves with public names if you want to use HDFS from outside the Hadoop cluster. A simpler solution is the enable HttpFS as a proxy and then access the proxy instead of HDFS directly.